# jQuery - Animate & Time interval

Tags: php, jquery

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $.get("database.php", function(data){
  var xp = data + "%";
  $('#exp_bg').animate({
   width: xp
  }, 1500, function() { });
 });

});
</script>
```

Database.php:

```
<?php
 $xp = 50;
 $level = 100;

 $xp_percent = $xp * 100 / $level;
 echo $xp_percent;
?>
```

What i'm trying to do, is that if $xp_percent increases in database.php, then #exp_bg's width will animate into desired width without refresh.

I tried to do that with time interval, which takes data from database.php every speciefed interval of time, but i failed doing that.

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: So the code you posted does not work or what is your problem? Do you get any error message? Is the request and response transmitted? Check with Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probably going to have to put it inside a setTimeout function like so:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() { 

$.get("database.php", function(data){
  var xp = data + "%";
  $('#exp_bg').animate({
   width: xp
  }, 1500, function() { });
 });


}, 1000);
```

This would check every second.